# center div on top of img without using position

Tags: html, css

I have a main container that contains an image and a div. What I want to achieve is to center the div on top of the image without having to use absolute or relative positioning on it. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```css
.imgCon {
  display: flex;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.imgCon img {
  width: 95.5%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.iconCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgCon">
  <!--center this-->
  <div class="iconCon">
    C
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.vitalground.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bart-the-Bear-II--e1637176991443.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: just wondering, if you want to be something on top, why do you place code for it at the bottom? why can't you move div tag before image?

Comment: its the same senario that's why. just edited it thought. @IłyaBursov

Comment: Are you trying to center div which includes 'C' inside?

Comment: ok, so you want it to be over image, then background-image is the most standard way probably

Comment: @IłyaBursov I was looking for a way without having to use background-image and geat' s answer worked. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of without using absolute positioning or changing your markup is to use a CSS Grid and make both elements occupy the same cell.

```css
.imgCon {
  display: flex;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
}

.imgCon img {
  width: 95.5%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: inherit;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.iconCon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  margin: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgCon">
  <img src="https://www.vitalground.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bart-the-Bear-II--e1637176991443.jpg" />
  <!--center this-->
  <div class="iconCon">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, this is the only possible way I see too without using background-image. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `background-image` property and tiny styling changes.

```css
    .imgCon {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 20rem;
      height: 20rem;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: blue;
      background-image: url("https://www.vitalground.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bart-the-Bear-II--e1637176991443.jpg");
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 80%;
    } 

    .iconCon {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 3rem;
      height: 3rem;
      margin: auto;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #000000;
    }

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-item: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="imgCon">
      <div class="container">
      <!--center this-->
      <div class="iconCon">
        C
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```